# Xamarin Profiler - Memory allocated

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, profiler, xamarin.forms

I want to optimize my Xamarin.Forms app, so I am starting to use **Xamarin Profiler**, and I can see that the initial memory allocated in my Android app is always around **50MB**.

The allocated memory is 50MB when the app starts, and it starts to increase around +1.6MB when I do push and around +0.2MB when I pull a page.

Of course, the more I navigate, the app goes slower and slower.

[image]

But I don't know if this amount is OK or if the app is consuming too much memory.

Guys, could you orient me a bit more about this? I am using MVVMCross (as MVVM framework) and I am not showing images in the MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating +1.6MB when navigate to page is normal. But it should be released after navigating back and GC calling.

If you are not caching the pages all memory should be released and you should not see 0.2MB added after pulling a page, so I think you do have a memory leaks. Making  memory snapshots and comparing between them can help you to detect memory leaks.

To check where memory leaks could be do the next steps:

1. Because Profiler manual snapshot is not working in latest (0.32) version set **Auto Snapshot** in Tools -> Options -> SnapShots. I recommend to set it to GC option.
2. Make snapshot (call GC if you set autosnapshot to GC option)
3. Navigate to Page you want to check memory leak.
4. Navigate back
5. Make snapshot again,
6. Compare between two snapshots and check what wasn't released

Try this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29612/how-to-find-memory-leaks-in-xamarin) for more info.

I hope this post is helpful for you.